# Derivation of the energy equation in the differential form

Tags: energy, fluid-dynamics

I'm trying to understand the derivation of the energy equation from fluid mechanics, that is presented in the book "Fluid Mechanics" (4th ed.) by Frank M. White (as you can see [here](http://library.aceondo.net/ebooks/Physics/_Fluid_Mechanics.pdf), page 231).

I can derive everything from the first step to the (4.48) and (4.49) expressions:

$$\rho\frac{de}{dt}+(\vec{V}.\nabla p)+p\left(\nabla.\vec{V}\right)=\left(\nabla.(k\nabla T)\right)+\left(\nabla.\left(\vec{V}.[\tau_{ij}]\right)\right)\hspace{20pt}(4.48)$$

$$\left(\nabla.\left(\vec{V}.[\tau_{ij}]\right)\right)=\left(\vec{V}.\left(\nabla.[\tau_{ij}]\right)\right)+\Phi\hspace{20pt}(4.49)$$

[**Note:** The (4.48) expression in the book is wrong. It misses the $p\left(\nabla.\vec{V}\right)$ term. The one that I presented here is the correct relation.]

where:

$e:=$system energy per unit mass;

$[\tau_{ij}]:=$viscous stress tensor;

$\Phi:=$viscous-dissipation function.

My doubt is about the following step, presented on the book:

*"Now substitute Eq. (4.49) into Eq. (4.48), using the linear-momentum equation (4.32)
to eliminate $\left(\nabla.[\tau_{ij}]\right)$ . This will cause the kinetic and potential energies to cancel, leaving a more customary form of the general differential energy equation".*

I tried to do what was asked, by making the following steps:

> By substituting (4.49) in (4.48) we get:
>
> $$\rho\frac{de}{dt}+(\vec{V}.\nabla p)+p\left(\nabla.\vec{V}\right)=\left(\nabla.(k\nabla T)\right)+\left(\vec{V}.\left(\nabla.[\tau_{ij}]\right)\right)+\Phi\hspace{20pt}(i)$$
>
> Then, we can write: $e=u+\frac{1}{2}V^2+gz$. And by assuming that $g\approx const$:
>
> $$\frac{de}{dt}=\frac{du}{dt}+\left(\vec{V}.\frac{d\vec{V}}{dt}\right)+g\frac{dz}{dt}\Leftrightarrow \frac{de}{dt}=\frac{du}{dt}+\left(\vec{V}.\frac{d\vec{V}}{dt}\right)+g\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}+g\left(\vec{V}.\nabla z\right)$$
>
> We have that $\nabla z=\vec{e_z}$ and $\vec{g}=-g\vec{e_z}$. So the relation above becomes:
>
> $$\frac{de}{dt}=\frac{du}{dt}+\left(\vec{V}.\frac{d\vec{V}}{dt}\right)-\left(\vec{V}.\vec{g}\right)+g\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}\hspace{20pt}(ii)$$
>
> By substituting (ii) in (i), we get:
>
> $$\rho\frac{du}{dt}+p\left(\nabla.\vec{V}\right)=\left(\nabla.(k\nabla T)\right)-\left(\vec{V}.\rho\frac{d\vec{V}}{dt}\right)+\left(\vec{V}.\rho\vec{g}\right)-(\vec{V}.\nabla p)+\left(\vec{V}.\left(\nabla.[\tau_{ij}]\right)\right)+\Phi-\rho g\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}\Leftrightarrow$$
>
> $$\Leftrightarrow \rho\frac{du}{dt}+p\left(\nabla.\vec{V}\right)=\left(\nabla.(k\nabla T)\right)-\left(\vec{V}.\left[\rho\frac{d\vec{V}}{dt}-\rho\vec{g}+\nabla p-\left(\nabla.[\tau_{ij}]\right)\right]\right)+\Phi-\rho g\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}$$
>
> The terms inside the rectangular brackets are null by the linear momentum equation, and so, we obtain:
>
> $$\rho\frac{du}{dt}+p\left(\nabla.\vec{V}\right)=\left(\nabla.(k\nabla T)\right)+\Phi-\rho g\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}$$

**To make the expression above be equal to the energy equation which is presented on the book, we would nee to have $\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}=0$. So, my doubt, is:**

**Should we assume that $\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}=0$, or is my expression derivation wrong?**

Comment: In the Eulerian formalism you are using, $t$, $x$, $y$, and $z$ are independent variables.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So due to the fact that z is independent of x and y we have that $W:=\frac{dz}{dt}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}$ and $\frac{d(gz)}{dt}=g\frac{dz}{dt}=gW=-\left(\vec{V}.\vec{g}\right)$. With this relation I can get the final expression.